# Hide a specific weight in forest plot in meta package

Tags: r

I want to hide a specific weight in a forest plot. In this example, I want to hide only the common and random weight for "Overall". Do you have an idea how to do it ?

```
meta_MCM_brut$exp <- paste(dataML2_MCM_brut$MCM_a, dataML2_MCM_brut$MCM_exp, sep = "/")
meta_MCM_brut$control.nb <- paste(dataML2_MCM_brut$MCM_c, dataML2_MCM_brut$MCM_unexp, sep = "/")
meta_MCM_brut$exp[meta_MCM_brut$exp == "NA/0"] <- "NA"
meta_MCM_brut$control.nb[meta_MCM_brut$control.nb == "NA/0"] <- "NA"
meta_MCM_brut$exp[meta_MCM_brut$studlab == "Overall1"] <- paste(sum(dataML2_MCM_brut$MCM_a,na.rm = TRUE), sum(dataML2_MCM_brut$MCM_exp, na.rm = TRUE), sep = "/")
meta_MCM_brut$control.nb[meta_MCM_brut$studlab == "Overall1"] <- paste(sum(dataML2_MCM_brut$MCM_c, na.rm = TRUE), sum(dataML2_MCM_brut$MCM_unexp, na.rm = TRUE), sep = "/")
meta_MCM_brut$studlab[meta_MCM_brut$studlab == "Overall1"] <- "Overall"

# Forest-plot
forest(meta_MCM_brut, fontsize = 8, text.fixed = "Fixed-effect model",
   text.random = "Random-effect model",
   leftcols = c("studlab", "exp", "control.nb"),
   leftlabs = c("Study", paste("Exposed", "\n", "(events/total)"), paste("Unexposed", "\n", "(events/total)")),
   prediction = TRUE, rightlabs = c("OR", "95%-CI", "Weight (fixed)", "Weight(random)"),
   text.addline1= 'CI : Confidence Interval, OR : Odds Ratio',
   header.line = 'below', addrows.below.overall = 1,plotwidth = "7cm", just = "center", print.Q = TRUE)
```

[Forest plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojz4f.png)

I tried to set w.common and w.random for this row to NA but forest function expects TRUE or FALSE or a number.

```
meta_MCM_brut$w.common[meta_MCM_brut$studlab == "Overall"] <- NA
```

Thank you

Comment: What package are you using? https://cran.r-project.org/package=forestplot ?

Comment: I use the meta package